# How to link multiple key events in AppleScript?

Tags: mail.app, applescript

I have been trying to write an AppleScript that would open the mail app register a save as key event (Shift+Command+S) wait 1.5 seconds, do a return key event ("Enter") and then wait another 1 second and then register a down arrow key event.

```
activate application "Mail"
repeat 2310 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using {shift down,command down}
    delay 1.5
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "return"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "DownArrow"
end repeat
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you have written already?

Comment: @grgarside Added

Comment: Since Mail.app can be scripted, I don't think you should use UI scripting but script Mail.app directly - to get an idea, open Mail.app with Script-Editor. + Script-Editor has a template for a "Mail Rule Action" (see menu File) and this is maybe even a way to go… (in Mail, we can apply a rule to a selection. Rules can be created in Mail's Preferences and they can run scripts). http://google.com/search?q=Mail.app+saving+emails+with+applescript

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "System Events" to repeat 2310 times
    tell application process "Mail" to set frontmost to true
    keystroke "s" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 1.5
    keystroke return
    delay 1
    key code 125
end repeat
```